# Tomcat giving 404 error with servlets

Tags: tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404, java

I have developed a Java web application using `Tomcat 7` and `Oracle JDK 1.7` with `NeatBeans 7.3`. My application runs on my local pc without any errors.

But after i hosted my application, I can't access servlets. It is giving me `404` error. I'm not used `web.xml` in my application to map servlets. I used `annotation` for it.

Hosted server use `Tomcat 7` and `Open JDK 1.7`.

What could be the issue ? How can i solve this ?

**New Update**

The place where i have purchased hosting gave me `cPanel` to upload files. There is no place to upload `war` file or place to upload files in to `webapps` director in tomcat. so i uploaded files in to `public_html` directory. i think this may be the issue. because when i'm trying to access servlet like `www.mysite.com/A` , server search for this in `root` directoy. but acctually it is not there. so it gives `404` error.

I thnik this may be the issue. Any suggesions ?

**UPDATED**

Annotation is like below

```
@WebServlet(name = "AddCustomer", urlPatterns = {"/AddCustomer"})
```

Download Servlet from [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50esntygokbcdhl/AddCustomer.java).

Directory structure.

[image: img]

Comment: is tomcat properly running ? are u able to open tomcat homepage?

Comment: @Bishan 404 means file not found,so check your code properly

Comment: @JunedAhsan yes. i can access `jsp` files in my application. but i can't access `servlets`.

Comment: @javaBeginner My app running on my local pc without errors. i got this error after hosting my app on another server.

Comment: @Bishan can u share the path where you have deployed your application under tomcat. Also share the dir structure of your webapp

Comment: @JunedAhsan looks likes an annotated servlet problem

Comment: @user2310289 i doubt because he says it works fine in eclipse+tomcat environment. So if he is using the same tomcat7 with the same application on any machine, it should work.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I'll update you ASAP. there is a some problem with my internet connection right now :(

Answer (score 1):

After deploying your project in to tomcat check in to "tomcat7\work\Catalina\localhost\your app" if the classes are present into the location. If classes are there then it should not be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

check the following:

- is the app below tomcat/webapps
- can you see it from tomcat manager
- any errors in the logs

Finally maybe post part of you web.xml and what url you are calling

**Edit**

So this is your code tree, but what has been deployed to your tomcat webapp directory?  Are your compiled classes under WEB-INF?

**Edit**
Do you new information received about the webapp being hosted in public_html I suggested you contact the resources of you hosted server provider to find out how to deploy correctly - maybe it is not even possible.

You could try getting a year long trial of EC2 from Amazon

Comment: I can access `jsp` files in my application. but i can't access `servlets`. I'm not used `web.xml` in my application to map servlets. I used `annotation` for it.

Comment: so you are using servlet3?  Maybe post your annotated servlet

Comment: I'll update you ASAP. there is a some problem with my internet connection right now :(

Comment: Yes. I have compiled classes under `WEB-INF`.

Comment: What URL are you using to try to access your servlet? What URL *does* work for JSPs?

Comment: `www.mysite.com/abc.jsp` to access `jsp`. `www.mysite.com/A` to access `servlet`. I can access `jsp`. but can't access `servlet`.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations don't work "out-of-the-box", you still have to `tell` the Tomcat to look for annotated `Servlet` classes. And to do that you need to use the correct version of the `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
  version="3.0">
```

I haven't used NetBeans, but like Eclipse it probably has project properties that let you specify Dynamic Web Project facet to **Servlet 3.0** value which gets translated to the `web.xml` line shown above.

You should check your project's `WEB-INF` folder for `web.xml` or try exporting it properly - a WAR file should (must?) contain `WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

## UPDATE

You "tell it" by using Servlet 3.0 version in the `web.xml` header. For earlier versions Tomcat won't expect annotation-marked servlets, i.e. you would have to list them manually in the XML.

As for the updated problem - you are getting 404 because the Apache HTTP Server (probably that is what is installed) doesn't understand WAR or JSP files, you need to configure it to forward the requests to the Tomcat which is probably on another port (default is 8080) - this is known as **AJP or HTTP proxy**, i.e. Apache server is acting as a front-side proxy to Tomcat. There are manny answers on that subject here at Stackoverflow.
You don't deploy a WAR file to `public_html` because that's where PHP or Perl webapps are deployed.

You should check with your hosting provider if you really have Tomcat installed, at which port is it and where to deploy your Java web application.

Comment: "you still have to tell the Tomcat to look"... really? How are you telling Tomcat to look for annotations?