# Java - Servlet 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am a newbie in servlet programming.

The following is my sample servlet code

**Sample.Java**

```
public class Sample extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();  

        String name=req.getParameter("name");//will return value  
        pw.println("Welcome "+name);  
        pw.close();  
    }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>sampleservlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Sample</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>sampleservlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Sample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="Sample" method="get">  
Enter your name<input type="text" name="name"><br>  
<input type="submit" value="login">  
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

**My problem**

When I right click on my project and then click `Run as -> Run on server`, I select the server, it asks me for to select a server and then I select the server to run. In the eclipse window a browser window is opened which has the address URL as http://localhost:8080/Sample/

[image]

When I click on `login` it gives me an error like this,

**HTTP Status 404 - /Sample/welcome**

---

**type** Status report

**message** /Sample/welcome

**description** The requested resource is not available.

---

**Apache Tomcat/7.0.62**

**Screenshot**

[image]

Why am I getting an error like this ?

**Other details**

Server:apache-tomcat-7.0.62
IDE: Eclipse Java EE kepler

Steps I tried to solve the problem

I tried these,

1. [Getting HTTP Status 404 error when trying to run servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871886/getting-http-status-404-error-when-trying-to-run-servlet)

**Result**

I did not see the `.class` files in `WEB-INF` folder.

2. [Tomcat giving 404 error with servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173430/tomcat-giving-404-error-with-servlets)

**Result**
In this path "tomcat7\work\Catalina\localhost\your app",the `work` folder was empty.

Please let me know if I need to post any more details.

**Directory structure from IDE**

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see project structure/tree. Maybe by screenshot from IDE

Comment: Did you make an entry in the `web.xml` file?

Comment: @Stan I have added the screenshot of project structure.

Comment: Thanks. So 'Sample' is your application name and servlet is mapped to '/Sample' URL inside your application. I think you should try to submit your form to the url 'Sample/Sample' (put it to Action attribute). First you can simply try in browser http://localhost:8080/Sample/Sample

Comment: It is weird. You have written `form action = Sample` but it is looking for `Sample/welcome`. Try to first rename your Servlet or Project, don't keep their name same. And then lets see what happens.

Comment: by clicking on login the url would be like http://localhost:8080/Sample/Sample?name=StackOverflow because your form action is sample..

Comment: @GPRathour I changed the servlet name from `sampleservlet` to `newserv` but I am getting the above same error.Please let me know what other details can I provide you ?

Comment: Add to the META-INF folder a context.xml file with this content:                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Sample"/>

Comment: No no. I din't mean that. I meant either change your Project name from `Sample` to like `SampleProject` or change the name of servlet class from `Sample` to `MyServlet` etc.

Comment: @GPRathour I renamed the project from `sample` to `Sampleproject` . I am still getting the same error. Please see [this](http://postimg.org/image/rm7ch4td5/).

Comment: @Zelldon I have added the `context.xml` file. Please see [this](http://postimg.org/image/rm7ch4td5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does work for me in tomcat 7 and eclipse.
Perhaps your index.html is not the same as the one your are posting because it's aimnig at Sample/welcome instead of Sample/Sample.

Tips:

- Make sure your index.html published version is the same as the one you have in your code. Modify the content and make sure it's publishing properly.
- Load http://localhost:8080/Sample/Sample?name=Random directly in your browser to see that the servlet is working propertly.
- Double click on Tomcat7 on your servers. Go to your Server path. e.g. C:\Java\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\Sample\WEB-INF\classes (your Sample class should be there) double check if you have permissions in those folders.
- Export your project as a WAR and deploy it directly in your [tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) without eclipse.
- Clean/Build your project
- On your Package Explorer under Servers/server.xml a you should have a declared context e.g.       `<Context docBase="Sample" path="/Sample" reloadable="false" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Sample"/></Host>`
  If you don't double check permisions in those folders. Add your tomcat7 server from the start again.

[image]

Comment: I have changed `<form action="Sample" method="get">` to `<form action="Sample/Sample]" method="get">`, I am getting the above same error. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried your second tip. I am still getting the same error. What could be wrong ?

Comment: @Codester Use <form action="Sample" method="get">  
Please, Enter your name<input type="text" name="name"><br> instead, let me know if you see the "Please, Enter..." I think the server is not refreshing your changes properly.

Comment: `<html>
<body>

<form action="Sample" method="get"> Please, Enter your name<input type="text" name="name"><br>

<input type="submit" value="login">


</form>
</body>
</html>` Still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you don't need to write the XML file for any servlet ;)

Just add the annotation `@WebServlet("/urlpattern")` and call this URL-pattern inside the JSP from `<form action="urlpattern">`

Only if you work on Eclipse.

```
@WebServlet("/Sample")
public class Sample extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    res.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();  

    String name = req.getParameter("name"); //will return value  
    pw.println("Welcome "+name);  
    pw.close();  
}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: <form action="urlpattern" method="post/get">